# What is the safest way to terminate EC2 instances with attached EBS volumes and MongoDB servers

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot

I'm currently in the development stages of a system that will use Mongo as its data store. The DB server will run on an EC2 instance, with the actual DB living on a separate EBS volume.

My question is this - supposing the database is up and running, but no data is being written to or read from it, how dangerous is it to terminate the EC2 instance from the AWS console, with respect to the DB data integrity? As I say, I'm not worried about any partially written data or anything like that, I'm referring really to the data already in the DB.

Further, can someone explain what impact snapshotting of the EBS volume has on the integrity of the data in the snapshot? On my local development server I always stopped Mongo before I rsync'd a backup to local storage so I'm not clear on the implications of taking an S3 snapshot of the EBS volume while the DB is running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminating an EC2 instance from the AWS console is the same as selecting the OS shutdown function from inside the VM, so provided Mongo obeys standard shutdown protocol and quiesces any open database channels gracefully, everything will be fine and there will be no integrity issues on the EBS volume.

Snapshotting EBS storage is not an atomic point-in-time process - it takes a finite amount of time, depending on the size of the EBS volume and the amount of change since the last snapshot, to create the new snapshot. Thus, if data integrity is a concern, you should always quiesce the database service before snapping the EBS data store. Similarly, if you are snapping the VM root EBS volume, you should stop the VM first.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, note that snapshotting an EBS volume could impact performance of that EBS volume.

When we snapshot our EBS volumes we see increased latencies.

Comment: Not sure why that would be the case - the snapshot process doesn't alter the EBS volume, and the snapshot data is actually stashed in S3 rather than EBS storage. If you mean EBS performance suffers *during* the snapshot process, this makes sense - the EBS system is performing a complete read of the EBS volume. But then, snapping an active EBS volume is a potentially dangerous exercise as I mentioned in my answer. Also: your answer would be more appropriate as a comment, as it doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is not what actually happens.
For Linux EC2 instances, terminating the instance simulates a power failure NOT a normal shutdown.  The /etc/rc.d shutdown scripts are NOT run.